# PHP - JSON empty values in database

Tags: php, json, rest

I am very new to php. I wan't to create json service which will be responsible to save registration form values in database. The problem is, it saves empty values in database. The problem is I can't understand how to get values from json and save them in database

php code

```
<?php

// Include confi.php
include_once('confi.php');


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Get data
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) :'';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['pwd']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']) : '';
    $status = isset($_POST['status']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']) : '';

    // Insert data into data base
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `test`.`users` (ID,`name`, `email`, `password`, `status`) VALUES (NULL,'$name', '$email', '$password', '$status');";
    $qur = mysql_query($sql);
    if($qur){
        $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Done User added!");
    }else{
        $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Error adding user!");
    }
}else{
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
}
@mysql_close($conn);

/* Output header */
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Sending values with post method

```
{
    "name":"aamir",
    "email":"a@a.com",
    "pwd":"12345678",
    "status":"yes"
}
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTOhj.png)
and I have followed this link
https://trinitytuts.com/build-first-web-service-php/

Comment: 1) Please refrain from using `mysql_*` functions as they were removed from PHP starting with version 7.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. 2) If you `echo $sql;`, does it show correct values?

Comment: @Jiri Hrazdil tihis line saves value if I put value in single quote after colon. like this line saves banana in database... $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) :'Banana';

Comment: That would mean that `$_POST['name']` is not set. The problem is in the part when you send values with POST method to your script...

Comment: @Jiri Hrazdil How to set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my opinion you have problems with client-server interactions.
PHP did not parse JSON data, it work only with url-encoded values.
So, your $_POST variable is empty array.

To get JSON formatted values, you should use

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php//input'), true));
```

Comment: I cant guess where to place this line. or  which code should I replace with this line

Comment: try to put it in the first line, and in second line write this: `var_dump($post);exit;`